# how to add linkbutton to a gridview and link it to a function with arguments in RowDataBound event

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

I have a case where i need to add a linkbutton with a gridview and link each linkbuttons with a function and pass different arguments.

Below is my source code.

```
protected void GridView1_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
    {
        ....
        LinkButton linkButton = new LinkButton();
        linkButton.Text = e.Row.Cells[5].Text;
        linkButton.CommandArgument = e.Row.Cells[0].Text;
        linkButton.ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.Blue;
        linkButton.Font.Underline = true;
        linkButton.Command += new CommandEventHandler(DisplayRecord_Click);
        //linkButton.Attributes.Add("OnClick", "DisplayRecord_Click");
        e.Row.Cells[5].Controls.Add(linkButton);
    }
}


protected void DisplayRecord_Click(object sender, CommandEventArgs e)
{
    string TransId = e.CommandArgument.ToString();
    ....
    ....
}
```

Please help me out guys.

Comment: Please show your code in `DisplayRecord_Click`. I think the issue is there.

Comment: DisplayRecord_Click is never called when those link buttons are clicked. Tried setting break point and it was never hit in first place. This is not a click event for any button. This is just a method i created.

Comment: What do you mean when you say: `I tried assigning Click event to CommandEventHandler`? How did you do that?

Comment: The idea is that each row will have a link button with text holding column1 information (say transaction-id). When that is clicked, i have to call the method DisplayRecord_Click which will get to know which transaction-id record should be displayed. I tried to assign click event to EventHandler   ---> linkButton.Click += new EventHandler(DisplayRecord_Click);

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You probably should be looking at [`Command` event handler](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.linkbutton.command(v=vs.110).aspx) instead of `Click` as you provided the `CommandArgument` in the code already. Just remember that the `Click` event is raised when the LinkButton control is clicked. This event is commonly used when no command name is associated with the LinkButton control.

```
linkButton.Command += new CommandEventHandler(DisplayRecord_Command);

void DisplayRecord_Command(Object sender, CommandEventArgs e) 
{
    var commandName = e.CommandName; 
    var commandArgs = e.CommandArgument;
    // ...
}
```

Comment: Thanks. I have updated my solution, but still i am not able to hit the method DisplayRecord_Command(). On clicking the linkbutton, the page_load() is called and that's it.

Comment: I just had to bind the gridview on postback to get it working. Page_Load was reinitializing the controls and the dynamic link buttons were lost eventually.

    if (!IsPostBack)
    {
        ....
    }
    LoadGridView();

Answer (score 0):

Try to use onclick in html:

```
runat="Server"  OnClick="LinkButton_Click"
```

Code Behind:

```
Protected void LinkButton_Click(Object sender,EventArgs e)
{
     // Your processs here....
}
```

Comment: am dynamically adding the linkbutton in gridview as mentioned above. I just need to call the method DisplayRecord_Click with argument and in that method, i will identify which row should be displayed based on the argument being passed as mentioned in the code. I guess, your answer posted wont help me here. Please clarify if my understanding is wrong.